# How to avoid water accumulation around the deck block?

Tags: deck, drainage

I have decided to build my floating deck but noticed that after a 3 days of rain, I have a pool of water around the deck block (see picture); which led me to believe that water doesn't drain properly. How can I fix it?

Thank you [image]

Comment: You have the block in a hole.  Three days of rain will usually fill up a hole, unless drains have been made.  Imagine when finish or before that hole will be filled in and the top will be made so it slopes away.

Comment: I'm confused - you appear to have a sheet of plastic, some of which is sitting in a hole. Why would you expect it *not* to fill with water? Where do you expect the water to go?

Comment: Fill the moat with blocks of styrofoam to support your deck framing so your floating deck can ***float!*** ...or, y'know, water runs downhill, make sure that the water from the moat has somewhere lower it can drain to, at 1-2% grade, rather than collecting in the moat and growing moat monsters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's all about the base](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH2hmJTVnHA). Typical setup is black plastic on the bottom and then gravel on top *up to at a little over the surrounding ground level*. You don't want it too much above the surrounding ground because the gravel will eventually erode (and also, why pay for more than you need, when you can just use slightly taller posts if you want the deck at a particular height). But you *definitely* don't want it below because then you end up with water problems.

I don't see any real fix except to disassemble, add several inches of gravel, reassemble.